# socket.io emit to room will disconnect some clients

Tags: node.js, socket.io, socket.io-redis

I am running a node.js server with socket.io 0.9. (xhr-polling)

I tried to simulate 300 clients connected to one big room.

I noticed that when I emit one single message to all members in the room, about 40-50 people in the room will be disconnected!

Syntax to emit message to everyone in the room:

`io.sockets.in(roomId).emit("abc", "efg");`

It is fine if I reduce the number of clients in the room to 100. Emit messages to room won't disconnect them.

This is definitely not acceptable. What is happening?

Comment: How are you simulating 300 clients?  Perhaps the simulation + xhr-polling is causing enough delays to cause disconnects.

Comment: I do noticed that the situation became better if I split my clients on multiple laptops. I am using this piece of code, where multi processes are spawned on laptop and each process simulates one client: https://gist.github.com/Siedrix/5065277. Is there a better way of simulating?

Comment: I suspect you have some responsiveness issues when you have only a couple processors for 300 clients as each processor can only do one thing at a time.  socket.io will disconnect if the connection goes unresponsive.  You could increase the heartbeat timeout to a much longer time for this particular test to keep the clients from disconnecting.